# Get the same value from another array and assign to object of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have two array of objects as following

```
          const arr1 = [
            {
              location_ID: 1,
              employee: "name",
              status: "available",
            },
            {
              location_ID: 2,
              employee: "name",
              status: "available",
            },
          ];

          const arr2 = [
            {
              assetLocation_ID: 1,
              location_Name: "Yangon",
            },
            {
              assetLocation_ID: 2,
              location_Name: "Mandalay",
            },
            {
              assetLocation_ID: 3,
              location_Name: "Magway",
            },
          ];
```

I am trying to find location name and insert a new field in `arr1` by `location_ID` so the final result would be like

```
          const arr1 = [
            {
              location_ID: 1,
              employee: "name",
              location_Name: "Yangon",
              status: "available",
            },
            {
              location_ID: 2,
              employee: "name",
              location_Name: "Mandalay",
              status: "available",
            },
          ];
```

I've tried `for` loop in arr1 and `arr2.find` for arr2 but objects of arr1 is always having location of ID 1, what am I doing wrong here ? Here is my code so far

```
          for (let i in arr1) {

            arr1[i].asset_Location = arr2.find((one) => {
              // one is always showing the first object of arr2
              return (arr1[i].location_ID = one.assetLocation_ID);
            }).location_Name;
    }
```

Comment: syntax error .. should be `==` here `arr1[i].location_ID = one.assetLocation_ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
const result = arr1.map(item => {
  const index = arr2.findIndex(asset => asset.assetLocation_ID === item.location_ID);
  if(index > -1) {
      return {...item, location: arr2[index].location_Name};
  }
  return item;
```

Or if you want to know what is wrong in your code,

```
for (let i in arr1) {
    arr1[i].asset_Location = arr2.find((one) => {
       // we need to return true or false from this method. You were assigning `one.assetLocation_ID` to `arr1[i].location_ID` instead of comparing them.
       return arr1[i].location_ID === one.assetLocation_ID;
    }).location_Name;
}
```

To learn more about the find method read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) article.